# Is memory allocated even when program ends?

Tags: c++

I am trying to allocate memory using new keyword in c++.

I was just wondering If memory is still allocated even after the program ends. meaning if there is still a memory leak.

Comment: No, all memory allocated by the program will be released when the program ends.

Comment: It actually depends on the host system.  Modern operating systems (windows, unix) running on hardware with a MMU (memory management unit) will - by design - recover memory from processes as they terminate.  On such platforms, memory leaks are mostly a concern for long-running processes.   Other, more basic, systems (e.g. software running "on the metal") will not recover allocated memory.

Comment: Makes me wonder if that is actually UB.